# React Card component won't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

working on a project using the Brewdog API which will render the different beers info in cards with their info. However I can't work out why the card components won't render. Any thoughts/help would be greatly suggested!

The API has fetched the data in the App.jsx and pass it down through props through CardArea all the way down the tree to card. The React Devtools show that the state has passed through the array of beer objects and i'm not getting any compiling errors or console errors.

Thank you in advance!

**APP.JSX**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import CardArea from "./components/CardArea";

const App = () => {

const [beers, setBeers] = useState([])


const getBeerData = () => {
  const API_URL = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers"

  fetch(API_URL)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((jsonResponse) => {
      setBeers(jsonResponse)
  })
}

useEffect(() => {
  getBeerData()
}, [])

return (
    <>
    <main className={styles.main}>
    <NavBar />
    <CardArea beers={beers}/>
    </main>
    </>      
  );
}

export default App;
```

**CardArea**

```
import styles from './CardArea.module.scss'
import CardList from '../CardList/CardList'
import NotFound from '../NotFound/NotFound'

const CardArea = (props) => {
const { beers } = props;

const contentJsx = beers.length ? (
    <CardList beers={beers} />
  ) : (
    <NotFound />
  );

  return <section className={styles.cardArea}>{contentJsx}</section>
}

export default CardArea;
```

**CardList**

```
import Card from '../Card/Card'
import styles from './CardList.module.scss'

const CardList = (props) => {
  const { beers } = props;

  const getBeerCardsJsx = (beer) => {
    <div className={styles.card} key={beer.id}>
      <Card beer={beer} />
    </div>
  }

  return <section className={styles.cards}> {beers.map(getBeerCardsJsx)} </section>
}

export default CardList
```

**Card.JSX**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Card.module.scss'

const Card = (props) => {
const { name, tagline, abv, description } = props.beer;


  return (
    <div className={styles.card}>
        <img className={styles.img} alt={name}></img>
        <section>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <h4>{tagline}</h4>
            <p>ABV: {abv}%</p>
            <p>{description}</p>
        </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Comment: “getBeerCardsJsx” doesn’t return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `getBeerCardsJsx` function, you're missing a return statement because your arrow function uses curly braces and you don't have an explicit return statement (the arrow bracket doesn't have implicit return whenever you use curly braces). Thus, the function ends up returning `undefined`, which React treats as nothing so you don't see anything rendered nor any errors.

To fix this issue, either replace the curly brackets with round brackets:

```js
import Card from '../Card/Card'
import styles from './CardList.module.scss'

const CardList = (props) => {
  const { beers } = props;

  const getBeerCardsJsx = (beer) => ( // instead of {
    <div className={styles.card} key={beer.id}>
      <Card beer={beer} />
    </div>
  ) // instead of }

  return <section className={styles.cards}> {beers.map(getBeerCardsJsx)} </section>
}

export default CardList
```

Or you can add an explicit return statement:

```js
import Card from '../Card/Card'
import styles from './CardList.module.scss'

const CardList = (props) => {
  const { beers } = props;

  const getBeerCardsJsx = (beer) => {
    return (
      <div className={styles.card} key={beer.id}>
        <Card beer={beer} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return <section className={styles.cards}> {beers.map(getBeerCardsJsx)} </section>
}

export default CardList
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing return keyword in getBeerCardsJsx function

Comment: What’s wrong with the “map” function?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).